# Voronoi diagram with different metric functions

Tags: geometry, reference-request, optimization, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $(X,d)$ and finite number of points $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ the [Voronoi diagram (or the Dirichlet cell)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) $C_i$ is given by
$$
C_i = \{x\in X:d(x,x_i)<\min\limits_{j\neq i}d(x,x_j)\}.
$$

I have two question:

1. Does anybody know if it was considered the case with different distance function, namely
   $$
   C'_i = \{x\in X:d_i(x,x_i)<\min\limits_{j\neq i}d_j(x,x_j)\}.
   $$
   where $(d_i)_{i=1}^n$ are all metric on $X$.
2. For the latter case - is it possible in general to find a metric $d'$ on $X$ such that $C'_i$ define above admits the representation
   $$
   C'_i = \{x\in X:d'(x,x_i)<\min\limits_{j\neq i}d'(x,x_j)\}.
   $$
   for any $i$.

*Edited*: the trivial answer on 2. is to set $d'(x,x) = 0$, $d'(x,y)=1$ if $x,y$ are from one cell and $d'(x,y)=2$ if they are from the different cells. I wonder if 2. can be solved without construction $C'_i$ first. Since the question now is not mathematically correct, I'll put a reference request tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might examine this classic (1985) paper by Paul Chew: "[Voronoi diagrams based on convex distance functions](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=323264)."  Google Scholar says this has subsequently been cited by 190(!) papers.  Another key search term is "generalized Voronoi diagrams," e.g.,
"[Fast computation of generalized Voronoi diagrams using graphics hardware](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=311567)."
But I am quite uncertain if these are relevant to your questions, which I have to admit 
are not too clear to me...